# Gradle - override the init script

Tags: java, gradle

By default `gradle init` creates a big comment about being created by `gradle init`, which I'd like to get rid of.

How can I override the default gradle init script?

Comment: You seem to be talking about two unrelated things - init scripts and the `init` task.

Comment: May be. All I mean is the template that is created by `gradle init`. But after reading a slice of doc it seemed the same to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently gradle doesn't provide an easy way to add your own templates or to make changes to existing templates. You could always make changes to gradle source and build a modified gradle distribution if you're so inclined. The template for the banner you're referring to lives in [this file](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/6a5413a9c7b428e70b3e76f14a3745bf5b2fce5c/subprojects/build-init/src/main/resources/org/gradle/buildinit/tasks/templates/javalibrary/build.gradle.template).

> /*
>    * This build file was auto generated by running the Gradle 'init' task
>    * by '${genUser.groovyComment}' at '${genDate.groovyComment}' with ${genGradleVersion.groovyComment}
>    *
>    * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
>    * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
>    * user guide available at ${ref_userguide_java_tutorial.groovyComment}
>    */